# How to close other apps

Tags: java, android

I have simple code for this problem.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(- activity -);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(- package name -);
```

or

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(- activity -);
activityManager.restartPackage(- package name -);
```

But i dont know what i can write on activity and package name areas.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: `context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)` for the first part. The value that you pass into those methods is the package name of the app that you are trying to affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you can't kill another apps / processes other than your own, simply because how Android OS architecture is set up. Every app lives in it's own sandbox with given resources and access to foreign ones is restricted. Although, I guess if you have rooted smartphone and root privileges, you could achieve your goal in linux kinda way, that is sending kill signal to given PID, try that out.

Comment: Link to documentation, please?

Comment: this is right. i can close an app with pid. but i dont know how i can get pids of all installed apps

Comment: Try ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses() and iterating over results

Comment: actually i wanna list like this:
string[] program_list = {"Whatsapp;pid", "Facebook,pid", "Youtube,pid"}

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: ofcourse i know you will not write code for me, if you say possible, i will start to try some algorithm. but i really dont know activity manager. i need simple example